# Android what is the formatted flag for string resource means?

Tags: android, android-resources

Basically question in the title.

I have seen several examples when people apply `formatted` flag to string resource, but can't find any official explanation, what this flag does.

Comment: where exactly is that tag set? Do you have an example? Also, is that for Java?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any format documentation on the flag in Android docs, but the flag is commonly used to indicate a string that should be formatted before being shown to the user.

The [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#formatting-strings) show an example of how to do this.

Per the example at the link, you may have a string resource named welcome_messages,

`<string name="welcome_messages" formatted="true">Hello, %1$s! You have %2$d new messages.</string>`

that allows you to format a welcome message with a custom name and number of messages. You would use this string as follows

`String text = getString(R.string.welcome_messages, username, mailCount);`

The `formatted` flag helps distinguish strings that need to be formatted in this matter before being shown to the user.

Comment: Where and how is this flag set? I have formatted strings in my app but I never saw the need to add any flags. I'm not sure I see it in the link you posted.

Comment: I edited the answer to show how the flag is set - there isn't a real need, but if you set the flag, you can programatically check for the boolean on the string resource to see if a string should be formatted.